# what is the meaning of custom program error: 0x70? (112 in decimal)

Tags: anchor, solana-program, error

I am getting this error in my contract written in Anchor.

I have already checked the custom errors of anchor at https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/error/enum.ErrorCode.html, but did not find anything 0x70 error code there.

Comment: does the instruction throwing this error have any CPI calls? if so, what are they?

Comment: It would be more helpful to post the program logs, that way it's possible to figure out what program is causing the error. It's not just anchor that shows errors.

Comment: Thank you @m_callens & @Henry E

I printed the program logs and figured out `mpl_token_metadata::instruction::update_metadata_accounts_v2` CPI was failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue was coming because `mpl_token_metadata::instruction::update_metadata_accounts_v2` CPI was failing.

The reason of failing of above CPI was: In my update instruction `collection` was `None` & the nft, I was trying of update, had their `collection` set beforehand.

Lesson Learned:

Printing out the program logs helps a lot to figure out the issue.

Comment: How do you get program logs if the whole transaction fails